# ¿Puedo un mismo sitio web para dos dominios diferentes?

Tags: dns

Buen día,

Soy nuevo en estos temas de DNS, y quisiera hacer la siguiente consulta:

Tengo mi dominio con su respectivo website alojado en mi hosting, por ejemplo:

**www.cebolla.com** y el website se almacena en el directorio **/public_html**

Queremos comprar un nuevo dominio para el público de Colombia, por ende este otro dominio será **www.cebolla.com.co**, sin embargo queremos que al ingresar a esta dirección se visualice la misma web almacenada en **/public_html**

Mi consulta es si es posible realizar esto o necesariamente tengo que tener contenidos distintos. He leído por ahí que de ser posible implicaría arriesgarse a ser sancionado por Google por duplicación de contenido. ¿Es cierto eso?

Mi hosting es Linux/Apache

Agradeceré su respuesta.

Comment: Yo te recomendaría crear Vhost, si tu hosting te da la posibilidad de hacerlos... Claro esta.

Comment: Yo no haría eso. Si en el dominio original creas una carpeta llamada `co`, en instalas allí otro sitio (por ejemplo con Wordpress u otro CMS, o a mano), podrás tener acceso a tu sitio colombiano haciendo: `co.cebolla.com` o bien `cebolla.com/co` por tanto, en este caso comprar otro dominio no se justifica. Otra cosa sería un dominio: `cebolla.co` que te daría quizá ventajas SEO para Colombia. Pero querer comprar un `cebolla.com.co`, además de feo, es (creo) un gasto innecesario. Pero lo más grave de lo que expones es querer tener **dos sitios con el mismo contenido**, ¿por qué eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tener un dominio para Colombia se justificaría solamente en el caso de que en tu sitio vaya a haber **una versión colombiana del sitio**.

La lectura y comprensión de: [***Gestionar sitios web multirregionales y multilingües***](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=es) de Google, creo que puede ayudarte a tomar la mejor decisión.

El documento empieza diciendo:

> Si tu sitio web **muestra contenido diferente en función del idioma,
>   el país o la región de los usuarios**, puedes optimizar su
>   posicionamiento en los resultados de búsqueda de Google.

O sea, una clave para determinar si hay que tener varios sitios es que éstos tengan **contenido diferente** (o el mismo contenido, pero en idiomas diferentes).

Una idea fácil para entender esto son las traducciones, un sitio puede tener una versión en inglés, una en español, una en francés...

En ese caso no corres riesgos de penalización y puedes tener incluso instalaciones diferentes dentro del mismo dominio principal, creando una estructura así:

```
cebolla.com/
    public_html   --sitio original con contenido por defecto (en español probablemente)
    uk            --sitio en inglés
    fr            --sitio en francés
    it            --sitio en italiano
```

Estamos hablando de un sólo dominio, con cuatro instalaciones.

Se puede acceder a las versiones mediante algo así:

```
cebolla.com/fr
```

o mediante

```
fr.cebolla.com
```

#### Ejemplo

Mi sitio original se llama: [`deiverbum.org`](https://www.deiverbum.org)
Y tiene una **versión** relativa a su app: [`app.deiverbum.org`](https://app.deiverbum.org)

Son:

- Dos sitios distintos (en cuanto a instalación y a contenido)
- Ambos en el mismo dominio

La estructura es:

```
public_html    --deiverbum.org
app            --app.deiverbum.org
```

---

Otra posibilidad es comprar dominios con las extensiones específicas por versión, la ventaja es que el SEO sería más específico. Por ejemplo, un dominio con extensión `.it` tienen más visibilidad en italia que algo como `dominio.com/it` o `it.dominio.com`. Si se busca esa ventaja, sería mejor entonces comprar los dominios:

```
cebolla.com
cebolla.uk
cebolla.fr
cebolla.it
cebolla.co  --ojo a esto
```

Luego instalas en cada uno **la versión del sitio** en el respectivo idioma.

La cuestión aquí es saber **si realmente tu sitio tendrá una versión colombiana**, si es sí, ¿qué justifica que la tenga? ¿qué diferencia tendría con la versión castellana? Si es el mismo contenido me parece descabellado duplicarlo. Vas a ser penalizado y el mantenimiento se hará cuesta arriba tarde o temprano.

Otra cosa es que en tu sitio haya una **sección para Colombia**. Entonces puedes poner ese contenido dentro de una carpeta `/colombia` y poner allí **lo propio de Colombia**.

Comment: Si bien es cierto que hasta hace no mucho se usaban los TLD para posicionamiento local, a día de hoy Google no parece prestarles demasiada atención. Por otro lado tienes herramientas como el Google Search Console, donde puedes especificar el pais al cual está dirigido tu sitio web y hará que tengas mas visibilidad en ese sitio que fuera.

Comment: @Emerita no es así, Google dice esto: *«Nos basamos en una serie de señales para determinar la mejor audiencia objetivo de una página: **Nombres de dominio de nivel superior de código de país (ccTLD)**. Estos códigos están asociados a países específicos (por ejemplo, .de a Alemania, o .cn a China), por lo que indican claramente a los usuarios y a los motores de búsqueda el país al que están dirigidos los sitios web. (En algunos países, el uso de los ccTLD está restringido a determinados usuarios, por lo que deberás realizar algunas averiguaciones previas ...»* (enlace arriba en la respuesta).

Comment: En mi experiencia, que es por lo que digo esto, los TLD no me han afectado en nada al SEO. Solo sirven de ubicación visual al usuario. Los restringidos no los he probado, por razones obvias. Esto, al ser algo oculto, va a variar de a quien preguntes, por mucho que Google diga, se sabe que hay cosas que afectan, aunque Google no lo diga en sus guías. Yo comento lo de los TLD bajo mi experiencia con tres TLD distintos, siendo estos .com .es y .net

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me parece muy didáctica. En este caso, no se trata de una página multilingue, es solo que tenemos nuestro negocio con clientes en Ecuador, de hecho nuestro dominio es com.ec, pero deseamos ahora ser visibles y tener clientes en otros países, Colombia es un ejemplo.

Comment: Me estoy volviendo viejo o algo: una buena pregunta, que daría para una excelente respuesta sobre como funciona el DNS y el protocolo HTTP ... ¿ Y publicas una respuesta dando una opinión sobre donde sería aconsejable y un ejemplo de organización de directorios ?

Comment: @Trauma la respuesta fue dada desde mi experiencia y sobre todo por considerar que no era conveniente tener dos sitios con el mismo contenido en el mismo idioma. Si consideras que otro tipo de respuesta puede aportar otro enfoque de solución, creo que la misma será bienvenida y será un gran aporte. Esa es una de las grandes ventajas de este sitio, que cada uno puede aportar su granito de arena según sus posibilidades y su conocimiento.

Answer (score 2):

Las dos respuestas son sí. Sí puedes hacer que un mismo contenido esté enlazado por dos direcciones web diferentes. Tan solo tienes que añadir todos los dominios que tengas en la configuración de Apache con ServerName y dirigirlos todos a la misma dirección del servidor.

Evidentemente los DNS de los dos dominios deben apuntar al mismo servidor.

En cuanto a Google, dejando a parte que el algoritmo del buscador es secreto y cambia a menudo, sí que parece que los contenidos duplicados se penalizan. Posiblemente no en los dos dominios pero sí al menos en uno de ellos, en aquel que Google decida que no es el original.

Comment: En ese caso, ¿Es preferible crear otro directorio para www.cebolla.com.co con contenido diferente?

Comment: Efectivamente @Carlos, el contenido duplicado se penaliza, y penaliza a quien lo suba después, es decir, no al dominio original, si no a los siguientes. El contenido a de ser original, no que sea creativo, si no que no exista en otros sitios, para evitar penalizaciones de Google.

Comment: @NekoLopez Depende de lo que quieras hacer, desde luego. Si quieres tener dos dominios que puedan ser accesibles desde las búsquedas de Google, mejor que cada uno de ellos tenga su propio contenido. Si lo que quieres es tener dos dominios que sean fáciles de recordar para dos comunidades de usuarios distintas, pero no te importa que uno de los dos no se posicione en Google, entonces sí creo que no pasa nada por compartir contenidos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias tener dos dominios para el mismo sitio, para ser SEO friendly sugiero que un dominio en lugar de cargar la web duplicada, haga la redirección de forma explicita de este modo el trafico seria dirigido a un único destino o contenido original. ( 301 )

Tambien podrias usar el tag `rel=Canonical` para indicar a los buscadores que efectivamente se trata de contenido duplicado ( En los links del contenido duplicado )

Comment: Pero en ese caso, en la barra de direcciones cada vez que ingreso a cebolla.com.co cambiaría a cebolla.com ¿No es así?

Comment: Podrias hacer un rewrite de url para mantenerlo esto podrias hacerlo desde un servidor web intermedio que gestione los requests a ambos dominios y hacer un proxy_pass hacia el contenido. ( Si es un hosting compartido podrias usar htaccess )

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr esto mediante el archivo .htaccess utilizando redirecciones. Si deseas que las solicitudes a pirulito.com y pirulito.com.co vayan al mismo lugar, puedes redirigir una de las versiones al dominio principal. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pirulito\.com\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pirulito.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Esto se interpreta de la siguiente manera:

> RewriteEngine On: Activa el motor de reescritura.

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pirulito.com.co [NC]: Verifica si el host solicitado es pirulito.com.co (ignora mayúsculas y minúsculas con [NC]).

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pirulito.com/$1 [L,R=301]: Si la condición anterior es verdadera, redirige la solicitud al mismo recurso en pirulito.com con un código de redirección 301 (permanent redirect).
> Asegúrate de ajustar el código según tus necesidades. Coloca este código en el archivo .htaccess en el directorio raíz de tu sitio web. Ten en cuenta que esto es una redirección 301, que indica que la redirección es permanente. Si deseas una redirección temporal, puedes cambiar R=301 a R=302. espero no haber llegado muy tarde!!!